# pyQt sub-menu backtrack

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a menu that has a structure like this:

```
Elements
    A
    B
    C\
        1\
            a
            b
        2\
            a
            b
    D
```

where Elements is displayed on the menubar anything with a `\` has a sub-menu.

In this example I have two `a`'s.  I want to be able to distinguish which `a` was clicked buy getting a list like this for example ['a', '1', 'C', 'Elements'].

Does Qt have a function where I can look up the top menus, or a way of backtracking?

I don't want to have to write a connection for each QAction in the menu because that would be a lot of extra code and rather redundant I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [QMenu.triggered](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmenu.html#triggered), [QMenuBar.triggered](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmenubar.html#triggered), and [QToolBar.actionTriggered](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtoolbar.html#actionTriggered) signals.

These signals all pass a reference to the action that was triggered, thus avoiding the need to connect each action to an individual slot.

An alternative approach would be to create a subclass of `QAction` that allows a handler to be passed as an argument to its constructor. All the boiler-plate connection code could then be factored out into the `__init__` method. This approach can be more flexible if there are a lot of actions that are re-used in several different menus and toolbars.

Answer (score 0):

QSignalMapper might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Signal mappers are used for re-emitting signals with a custom identifier, so that all the signals can be handled by a single slot. This means the signal mapper would need to be connected to the `triggered` signal of each individual action, which does not appear to be what the questioner wants.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of solving the problem, below, but I'm going with ekhumoro's answer because his was is cleaner I think.

```
backtrack = [str(event.text())]
previousWidget = event.associatedWidgets()[0]
while previousWidget.__class__.__name__ != 'QMenuBar':
    backtrack.append(str(previousWidget.title()))
    previousWidget = previousWidget.parent()
print backtrack
```